# Working with file containing unmatched braces

Tags: file, tcl, curly-braces

I need to modify a file containing several lines with unmatched braces like:

```
  rmsd {
    atoms {
      atomsFile 
      atomsCol B
      atomsColValue 1
    }
```

So if I do this:

```
set fp [open "fpor.conf" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp
set confFile [split $file_data "\n"]

set inOut [open "us.in" w]

foreach line $inFile {
     if {[lindex $line 0] == "atomsFile"} {
        lappend line "us.pdb"
     }
     puts $inOut "$line"
}
close $inOut
```

The script fails with the error:
unmatched open brace in list. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to update the file as follows,

```
atomsFile us.pdb
```

then, instead of checking for the list index of presence, check only the word.

i.e.

```
if {[regexp atomsFile $line]} {
    lappend line "us.pdb"
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You read the file into a list of lines, then you iterate over the lines. Your mistake is treating the line like a list instead of a string. This will help you:

```
foreach line $confFile {
    set fields [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
    if {[lindex $fields 0] eq "atomsFile"} { ...
```

- Here, `split` is insufficient to find the whitespace-separated words, because `split` splits on individual characters:

  ```
  % set line {      atomsFile }
        atomsFile 
  % split $line
  {} {} {} {} {} {} atomsFile {}
  ```

---

Or just do regex matching:

```
foreach line $confFile {
    if {[regexp {^\s*atomsFile} $line]} { ...
```

---

As you noticed, you cannot handle any arbitrary string as if it is a list.

```
% set line "no { match here"
no { match here
% lindex $line 0
unmatched open brace in list
% lindex [split $line] 0
no
```

Answer (score 0):

When the contents of a file are an improper list, it's better to treat it as text only.

```
set fp [open "fpor.conf" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp
set fp [open "us.in" w]
puts -nonewline $fp [regsub -line -all {^(\s*atomsFile.*)$} $file_data {\1us.pdb}]
close $fp
```

or, a little more high-level:

```
package require fileutil

proc appendIt file_data {
    regsub -line -all {^(\s*atomsFile.*)$} $file_data {\1us.pdb}   
}

::fileutil::writeFile us.in [appendIt [::fileutil::cat fpor.conf]]
```

Documentation:
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm),
[regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)